# Merging river network features which should belong to same tributary of certain stream order in ArcMap without using Dissolve tool

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, hydrology, arc-hydro, strahler

I processed the DEM data through Arc Hydro to get the vector data of the river network. I recently tried to calculate the Horton-Strahler ratios and suitable flow accumulation threshold of it, yet these elements which should be divided into the same tributary of a certain stream order were actually divided into different vector features. Thus I am unable to extract the value correctly.

For the river networks with fewer tributaries and lower drainage densities, it is feasible and precise to edit the tributaries manually by the Dissolve tool of ArcMap. However, for the river networks with a mass of tributaries and repeated calculations, I am confused that how to use other methods with more convenient and less human errors to obtain the results in batches?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  If you want to ask a similar question about your options in QGIS or ArcGIS Pro then please do that in separate questions.

Comment: How many outlets in your system? Why are you merging reaches? Is it a total length of individual.order you are after?